# Stripe Api + Go: send more product than one from model to checkout session

Tags: go

I want to send more products from my sqlite database to stripe checkout session but i dont know how i can to do. I prefer to use "for" loop but how i can implement this in this code.

**My code for single product:**

```
var cart []models.Cart

Db.Where("user_id = ?", user_id).Find(&cart)

params := &stripe.CheckoutSessionParams{
    Mode: stripe.String(string(stripe.CheckoutSessionModePayment)),
    LineItems: []*stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemParams{
        &stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemParams{
            PriceData: &stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemPriceDataParams{
                Currency: stripe.String("usd"),
                ProductData: &stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemPriceDataProductDataParams{
                    Name: stripe.String(cart[0].Product_title),
                },
                UnitAmount: stripe.Int64(cart[0].Product_price * 100),
            },
            Quantity: stripe.Int64(1),
        },
    },
    SuccessURL: stripe.String("http://localhost:3000/member/order/success"),
    CancelURL:  stripe.String("http://localhost:3000/member/order/cancel"),
}
```

Comment: O course in this code I create session like this: s, err := session.New(params)

Comment: I created something similar in nodejs: https://pastebin.com/RqjxUb1v

Answer (score 0):

stripeBody is the body that you parse from the body
then loop throw your lineItems and put then inside a variable like stripeItems and then add it to params

```
var stripeItems []*stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemParams
for _, cart := range stripeBody.Cart {
    stripeItems = append(stripeItems, &stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemParams{
        PriceData: &stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemPriceDataParams{
            Currency: stripe.String("usd"),
            ProductData: &stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemPriceDataProductDataParams{
                Name:   stripe.String(cart.Name),
                Images: stripe.StringSlice([]string{cart.Image}),
            },
            UnitAmount: stripe.Int64(int64(cart.Price) * 100),
        },
        Quantity: stripe.Int64(cart.Quantity),
    })
}



params := &stripe.CheckoutSessionParams{
    Mode:          stripe.String(string(stripe.CheckoutSessionModePayment)),
    LineItems:     stripeItems,
    CustomerEmail: &stripeBody.Address.Email,
    SuccessURL:    stripe.String(domain + "/success"),
    CancelURL:     stripe.String(domain + "/cancel"),
}
s, err := session.New(params)
```